# how to create PDF a fpdf using using PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I trying to create PDF using FPDF by PHP. Here is my code.

```
require 'fpdf.php';
$pdf= new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', "", 18);
$pdf->Ln();
$fruits=["apple", "Strawberry", "Banana"];
$animals=['Lion', 'Camel', 'Dog'];
$numbers=[1,2,3];

$i=0;
while($i<count($array))
{
    $pdf->Cell(5, 5, $fruits[$i]);

    $pdf->Cell(35, 35, $animals[$i]);
$pdf->Cell(35, 35, $numbers[$i]);
    $i++;
}
$pdf->output();
```

I am getting the output in this way

```
apple Strawberry Banana
Lion Camel Dog
1    2    3
```

But I am looking the output like with table format. I Have tried multiple ways using html tags like 
, and regex '\r\n'. But I didn't get output. I am getting the output in the above format only.

```
apple         Lion   1
Strawberry    Camel  2
Banana        Dog    3
```

Thanks in advance and welcome with all new ideas.
Thanks You

Answer (score 0):

First, `$array` is undefined in the condition of your `while` statement.

Your table is disarranged because you are adding cells with different heights.

This should work:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($fruits))
{
    $pdf->Cell(35, 8, $fruits[$i]);
    $pdf->Cell(35, 8, $animals[$i]);
    $pdf->Cell(35, 8, $numbers[$i]);
    // Insert a line break at the end of each row.
    $pdf->Ln();
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Am also use the same issues, I am using table

check my below code

```
     $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('times','B',16);
        $htmlTable ="";
        while($i>count($array)){
            $htmlTable +='<TABLE>
            <TR>
            <TD>'$fruits[$i].'</TD>
            <TD>'.$animals[$i].'</TD>
            <TD>'.$numbers[$i].'</TD>
            </TR>
            </TABLE>';
            $pdf->WriteHTML2("<br>".$htmlTable);
        }
```

In the above working perfectly.

Comment: This answer is useless. (1) Your code requires the "HTML table" add-on, but you do not mention it. (2) Depending on the value of
`$i`, your `while` loop will run either infinitely or will not be entered at all. (3) You are confusing `+=` with `.=`. (4)
Adding a new HTML table for each "row" will very likely result in misaligned columns.